# JPA @Query java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Have problem with this code

```
public interface CharityRepository extends CrudRepository<Charity,Long> {

  @Query("select sum(sponsorSum) from Charity")
  Integer totalCharitySum();
}
```

Throw exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\maraphonskills(3)\target\classes\com\maraphon\maraphonskills\controllers\AdminController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'charityServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\maraphonskills(3)\target\classes\com\maraphon\maraphonskills\service\CharityServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'charityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Short com.maraphon.maraphonskills.repository.CharityRepository.totalCharitySum()!
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'charityServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [D:\IdeaProjects\maraphonskills(3)\target\classes\com\maraphon\maraphonskills\service\CharityServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'charityRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Short
>   com.maraphon.maraphonskills.repository.CharityRepository.totalCharitySum()!
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'charityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Short com.maraphon.maraphonskills.repository.CharityRepository.totalCharitySum()!
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Short com.maraphon.maraphonskills.repository.CharityRepository.totalCharitySum()!
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

But this code works fine

```
public interface CharityRepository extends CrudRepository<Charity,Long> {
  @Query("select sum(sponsorTarget) from Registration")
  Short totalSum();
}
```

@Modifying doesn't help.What could be the problem?

**Charity Code**

```
 @Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "registrations")
@Data
public class Charity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Lob
    private String description;
    private String fileName;
    private Short SponsorSum;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "charity")
    public Set<Registration> registrations = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

**Registration code**

```
    @Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "sponsorShips")
@Data
public class Registration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Runner runner;
    private String registrationDateTime;
    @ManyToOne
    public Charity charity;
    @ManyToOne
    public RaceKitOption raceKitOption;
    @ManyToOne
    public RegistrationStatus registrationStatus;

    private Short sponsorTarget;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "registration")
    public Set<SponsorShip> sponsorShips = new HashSet<>();
   // public RegistrationEvent registrationEvent;
}
```

Comment: Please post `Charity` code

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Mind the capital letter at the beginning of `sponsorSum` (in query) vs `SponsorSum` (in entity)

Comment: OOOOOOOH My.... Didn't notice this.Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error message says: "Validation failed for query for method public abstract **java.lang.Short** com.maraphon.maraphonskills.repository.CharityRepository.totalCharitySum()". So no, it doesn't work with Short.

Comment: No,It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

***Tips:*** Java is case sensitive.

The issue is between the use of lowercase sponsorSum, in your **CharityRepository** interface:

```
@Query("select sum(sponsorSum) from Charity")
```

And uppercase one in your **Charity** class:

```
private Short SponsorSum;
```

Use the same case in both, and it will solve your issue.